# Adobe Flex - generate XML file

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I am trying to generate XML file in Adobe Flex 4.6. This is my code.

```
    public var prefsFile:File;
    [Bindable] public var prefsXML:XML;
    public var stream:FileStream;

private function createXMLData():void 
{
        var location:String = "";
        prefsXML = <root/>;

        var i:int = 0;
        if(photoList.length > 0){
                for(i; i< photoList.length; i++){
                   prefsXML.P[i] = photoList[i]; //photoList is an array which contain names
            }
        }

        var outputString:String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
        outputString += prefsXML.toXMLString();
        outputString = outputString.replace(/\n/g, File.lineEnding);

        trace("XML file: " + prefsXML.toXMLString());
        stream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(prefsFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);
        stream.close();
    }
```

This is my output.

```
<root>
  <P xmlns="views:AddDetails">16032012155637.jpg</P>
  <P xmlns="views:AddDetails">16032012155642.jpg</P>
</root>
```

I don't know how `xmlns="views:AddDetails"` is added inside `<P>` tag.

Can anyone please explain to me? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  I tested out your code and got the same result, although I didn't expect to:

```
<root>
  <P xmlns="Test_XMLNS">16032012155637.jpg</P>
  <P xmlns="Test_XMLNS">16032012155642.jpg</P>
</root>
```

For me, it added the name of my test project as the `xmlns`, so I suspect the name of the class that contains your code is AddDetails in the view package.

Additionally, this only seems to happen when you are creating an element at a specific index using the XML dot operator - it doesn't happen normally.  That is,

```
prefsXML.P[i] = photoList[i];
```

causes the xmlns to be added, but

```
prefsXML.P = photoList[i];
```

doesn't.

---

In any case, you can fix it by adding your new elements slightly differently:

```
    if(photoList.length > 0){
      for(i; i< photoList.length; i++){
        prefsXML.appendChild(<P>{photoList[i]}</P>); //photoList is an array which contain names
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, the attribute value is the name of the class. Do you think is this a bug? Thank you again this helps me lot.

Comment: I couldn't say whether this was intended behaviour or not, but it does seem suspicious that it only happens when you have the [i] at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The XML takes the namespace of the file by default.

It's a bit dirty fix but it works, put this before var `outputString:String =...`

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace();
var node:XML;
prefsXML.addNamespace(ns);
prefsXML.setNamespace(ns);
for each (node in prefsXML.descendants())
    node.setNamespace(ns);
```

Hope that helps.